# Unable to make condition based input fields using streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements, streamlit

```
import os
import nltk
import ssl
import streamlit as st

st.write("Enter value")
counter=0
a=st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
counter+=1
if a==2:
    st.write('2')
    st.write('Enter b')
    counter+=1
    b=st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
    if b==3:
        st.write('Enter c')
        counter+=1
        c=st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}")
        print('bye')
```

I want to take input based on if-else conditions using streamlit which I am unable to do so. Somehow the conditions are not working. Only the first text input is being displayed.
[image]
When I enetered 2, the further fulfilling conditional text fields are not appearing. Iwant to develop a chatbot using streamlit kindly help me in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The `text_input()` returns string [docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.text_input) but you try to compare it with `int`, so it will not work as you noticed. So either cast your value to `int` (mind the crap user can type which would raise an error, so `try/catch` perhasp too?)

```py
a = int(st.text_input("You:", key=f"user_input_{counter}"))
```

or compare with strings

```py
if a == '2':
   ...
```